# Insulating under floor boards with foil insulation

Tags: insulation, subfloor

I am looking to insulate underneath the floorboards in a ground floor suspended timber floor with no access from below. The joists are 4" (10cm) deep. I have some concerns regarding airflow under the floor so I plan to install two new air bricks first. My plan for the insulation is:

- Staple gun plastic barrier fencing running perpendicular to the joists so it sags between each joist and runs over the top of the joists
- Lay 10cm mineral wall insulation in the netting between the joists

My questions is, should I then lay Thermawrap (or similar) foil insulation on top of the joists before nailing down the floorboards? I've read this is a good idea, but wouldn't this cause spring in the floorboards? My plan is to sand the boards and not lay a carpet.

The foil I am looking at is 3.7mm thick and has a thermal resistance R value of 1.455 W/mK (equivalent to 65mm mineral fibre according to the packaging). It says "suitable for walls, roofs and floors", but will this create issues with condensation / moisture?

Comment: "The joists are 4" Something seems not right about that.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I was also surprised by the size of the joists. Upstairs are substantial larger, but downstairs the joists are 2" x 4" spaced every 40cm.